# Xcode Failed to build module '***'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, xcode15

I am facing this issue while I am trying to import my custom SDK. The xcode version I used is 15.2.

`Failed to build module '***'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.9.2 (swiftlang-5.9.2.2.56 clang-1500.1.0.2.5)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.`

The SDK is build with anothe Xcode may be lower version than 15.2. What will be the solution to build the project in my xcode 15.2 on macbook ari m1

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can try disabling the Swift version check in the build settings of the SDK. However, this may lead to compatibility issues or unexpected behaviour and is therefore not recommended unless absolutely necessary